# compile error while using java 8 api to stream on CompletableFuture

Tags: java-8, completable-future

This works:

```
public Long getMaxSalary(List<CompletableFuture<EmployeeData>> futures) {

CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));
CompletableFuture<List<EmployeeData>> employeeDataList = allDoneFuture.thenApply(v ->
                            futures.stream()
                                    .map(f -> f.join())
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

List<EmployeeData> rc = employeeDataList.get();
OptionalLong op = rc.stream().mapToLong(r -> r.salary()).max();
return op.getAsLong();


}
```

trying to make this concise throwing compiler errors in IDE. I cannot figure out what the error is. I am trying to combine it in one stream.

```
    public Long getMaxSalary(List<CompletableFuture<EmployeeData>> futures) {

    CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));

    return allDoneFuture.thenApply(v ->
                                futures.stream()
                                        .map(f -> f.join())
                                        .mapToLong(r -> r.salary())
                                        .max()).getAsLong();

    }
```

Comment: `thenApply` returns a `CompletableFuture` which doesn’t have a `getAsLong()` method. You would need `.join().getAsLong()`, but [as Misha said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50522089/2711488), that’s all unnecessary when you are blocking the current thread anyway. There is, by the way, [an interesting article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) about the behavior of passing a pre-sized array to `Collection.toArray`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point in using `allOf` and `thenApply` if you are going to block the current thread anyway with an immediate `.get()`

```
return futures.stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .mapToLong(EmployeeData::salary)
    .max()
    .getAsLong();  // or throw if futures is empty
```

`allOf` approach would be useful if you wanted to return `CompletableFuture<Long>` and let the clients of your method decide when and in what thread to await completion.

Comment: are you not waiting here. I dont see a `.get()` invoked. btw `allOf` returns CompletetableFuture<Void>.

Comment: Exactly.  If you are going to wait anyway, don't bother with `allOf`, just use `join` on all the futures.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
return allDoneFuture.thenApply(v -> futures.stream().map(f -> f.join())).get()
        .mapToLong(empData -> empData.salary()).max().getAsLong();
```